# Python Invalid Syntax (subprocess)

Tags: python, syntax

I found troubles when running this command via `subprocess.check_output()`:

```
sed 's/^.*UUID="/UUID="/'
```

Python returns invalid syntax although this works on linux command line.

My Python code:

```
subprocess.check_output('sudo blkid | sed 's/^.*UUID="/UUID="/' | cut -d '"' -f 2', shell=True)
```

and the error I get:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    subprocess.check_output('sudo blkid | sed 's/^.*UUID="/UUID="/' | cut -d '"' -f 2', shell=True)
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please show us your Python code; how did you handle the quoting in a string literal?

Comment: Here it is: subprocess.check_output('sudo blkid | sed 's/^.*UUID="/UUID="/' | cut -d '"' -f 2', shell=True)

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to add that information. Please include the *full error message* as well.

Comment: I've filled in the error for you, based on what I'd expect it to be given your comment. Please correct this if the error is not accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not escaping your quotes; you cannot just include `'` in your string literal without ensuring that it is not seen as the *closing* quote.

So instead of:

```
subprocess.check_output('sudo blkid | sed 's/^.*UUID="/UUID="/' | cut -d '"' -f 2', shell=True)
```

use:

```
subprocess.check_output('sudo blkid | sed \'s/^.*UUID="/UUID="/\' | cut -d \'"\' -f 2', shell=True)
```

or use triple-quoting:

```
subprocess.check_output('''sudo blkid | sed 's/^.*UUID="/UUID="/' | cut -d '"' -f 2''', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Popen to pipe without using `shell=True` writing your sudo password to `stdin`:

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

p1 = Popen(['sudo', '-S', 'blkid'], stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdin.write("password\n")

p2 = Popen(['sed','s/^.*UUID="/UUID="/'], stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
p3 = Popen(['cut', '-d', '"', '-f' ,'2'],stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=PIPE))

p2.stdout.close()

out, err = p3.communicate()
print(out)
```

Comment: What's the point of this method in comparison to shell=True?

Comment: @BlenderUser , how are you entering your password? There are also many reasons not to use shell=True,  search shell=True on SO